# Apply NumberFormatInfo to a DataSet, DataTable or etc

Tags: c#

I am trying to apply NumberFormatInfo to a DataSet, DataTable but the NumberFormatInfo Settings are not applying on the DataSet/DataTable. I am trying to apply NumberFormatInfo on the DataSet/DataTable using the

t_DS stands for DataSet as

```
    NumberFormatInfo myNfi = new NumberFormatInfo();
    myNfi.NumberNegativePattern = 0;
    myNfi.NumberDecimalDigits = 0;
    myNfi.NumberGroupSeparator = "";
```

t_DS.Tables[0].Locale.NumberFormatInfo = myNfi;

and same for the DataTable aswhere t_DT stands for the DataTable

```
    NumberFormatInfo myNfi = new NumberFormatInfo();
    myNfi.NumberNegativePattern = 0;
    myNfi.NumberDecimalDigits = 0;
    myNfi.NumberGroupSeparator = "";
```

t_DT.Locale.NumberFormatInfo = myNfi;

But these Settings are not applying on the t_DS/t_DT variables.

Actually what i am trying to achieve is that i want to remove the Decimals from the DataSet, i know it is possible through a SQL Query but i want to apply these settings on the DataSet/DataTable directly instead of doing it through Query.

Kindly please help me in this.

Looking for a favorable reply.

Thanks

Comment: If you want more help please explain what it is you're trying to achieve. I mean, why do you want to remove the decimals? Is it for display purposes?

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, [DataTable.Locale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.locale.aspx) only applies to string comparison within the table. See the following quote:

> **DataTable.Locale Property**
>
> Gets or sets the locale information used to compare strings within the table.

Comment: Then it means that, even if there are numeric columns, then i can't apply the NumberformatInfo on these Numeric columns, to accept the format i am providing.
Will you please provide me with a proper example.
i am unable to understand this case of Locale in a DataTable, 
because in the above example, there is no change in the DataTable.
Than how come we can easily set the DateFormat in the DataTable.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you are trying to do exactly. Are you trying to format the values for display purposes? Or maybe for db consumption? It's hard to come up with a "proper example" when I don't quite understand what I'm supposed to demonstrate. ;)

Comment: Sorry for late comment, actually what you got is true, i want to remove the decimals for display purposes only.
kindly please reply and help me in this.
Thanks for your comments